# Running pyinstaller with Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm very new to using docker and Jenkinfiles in Jenkins.
Currently, I want to run a docker container (pyinstaller-windows) on linux, so I wrote the following Jenkinsfile to test it:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Deliver') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'cdrx/pyinstaller-windows:python3'
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'cd app/'
                sh 'pip install -r requirements.txt'
                sh 'cd gui'
                sh './gui_to_exe.sh' //containing pyinstaller command
            }
            post {
                success {
                    archiveArtifacts 'appName.exe'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After running it in Jenkins, I received the following error message:

```
     cdrx/pyinstaller-windows:python3 cat
        $ docker top 8...5 -eo pid,comm
        [Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
        [Pipeline] }
        [Pipeline] // withEnv
        [Pipeline] }
        [Pipeline] // node
        [Pipeline] }
        [Pipeline] // stage
        [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
        java.io.IOException: Failed to run top '8...5'. Error: Error response
    from daemon: Container 8...5 is not running.

at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.listProcess(DockerClient.java:152)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.WithContainerStep$Execution.start(WithContainerStep.java:201)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:322)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:196)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:124)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker$Image.inside(Docker.groovy:140)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker.node(Docker.groovy:66)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker$Image.inside(Docker.groovy:125)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.declarative.DockerPipelineScript.runImage(DockerPipelineScript.groovy:54)
    at 
...
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Check the following minimal pipelinne. I fixed the issues I observed. Other than that, I'm not sure from where you are getting the `app` directory. Probably you may want to mount the workspace to your Container if you have any sources in the host machine.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Deliver') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'cdrx/pyinstaller-windows:python3'
                    args "--entrypoint=''"
                }
            }
            steps {
                echo "Something"
                sh '''
                    cd app/
                    pip install -r requirements.txt
                    cd gui
                    ./gui_to_exe.sh
                '''
            }
            post {
                success {
                    archiveArtifacts 'appName.exe'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I have a couple of questions, I'll start with this one: what's the purpose of  " ' " that you used next to pip install and cd gui ?

Comment: @Gaston Sorry, that was a typo, Fixed it :) Simply if you are changing a Dir and executing some command within that DIr you need to execute all commands in the same session. that's why the sh lines were combined.

Comment: alright, thanks. I got the following error when using the Jenkinsfile: `+ pip install -r requirements.txt
Fatal Python error: init_sys_streams: can't initialize sys standard streams
OSError: [WinError 6] Invalid handle` couldn't find something relevant in the net, do you know what the problem could be ?

Comment: I'm not really sure, Since we bypassed the entry point, something is probably not set properly. The best way to debug this is, first try to run the steps manually in the container.